# SharePoint 2016: Share document with 250 users, only 200 users received an email

Tags: 2016, exchange, outgoing-email

We are using SharePoint 2016 and Exchange 2013. We have shared a document with 250 users and enabled email notification. Only 200 users did receive an email. The other 50 users didnt receive an email. We did check the logging in Exchange and can see there are comming in some batches with multiple recipients.

Who is creating these batches? SharePoint or Exchange?